# Count occurrences in javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

`Object {green: 3, red: 2, blue: 1, yellow: 1, mint: 3}`

I want to loop through this object and return the keys with the most occurrences (by value) in an array. In this instance, it would be mint and green like `["mint", "green"]`.

So far, I got this

```
for (var i = 0; i < key(obj).length; i++) {
  ... // no idea
}
```

Any help or direction appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: As far as I can tell, red and yellow did occur as well.. I don't get what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var obj = {"green": 3, "red": 2, "blue": 1, "yellow": 1, "mint": 3},
    keys = Object.keys(obj),    // get all keys as array
    max = Math.max.apply(Math, keys.map(function(key) { return obj[key]; })),    // find the biggest number of occurrences
    result;
 
result = keys.filter(function(key) {    // find the relevant keys
 return obj[key] == max;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

```
var maxValue = -10000000;
for(var prop in obj) {
 if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
  continue;
 }
 if(obj[prop] > maxValue) {
  maxValue = obj[prop];
 }
}
// show maxValue
```

Note: you need `obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)` because object in js has some special properties, which you don't need in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = {green: 3, red: 2, blue: 1, yellow: 1, mint: 3}
var maxProperty = null, maxValue = -1;
for (var prop in data) {
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    var value = data[prop]
    if (value > maxValue) {
      maxProperty = prop
      maxValue = value
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this only get the first largest element (in this case green) and skin all the others (in this case mint)?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```js
var someObjects = {
  green: 3,
  red: 2,
  blue: 1,
  yellow: 1,
  mint: 3
};


function findOccurances(of, inn) {
  var array = [];
  for (var obj in inn) {
    if (someObject[obj] == of) {
      array.push(obj);
    }
  }
  return array;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:
I thought a more consie solution would be in order. Here is one:

```js
var bar = { green: 3, red: 2, blue: 1, yellow: 1, mint: 3 };

var findMaxProperties = function (foo) {
  var keys = Object.keys(foo);
  var max = keys.map(function (key) {
    return foo[key];
  }).reduce(function (previous, current) {
    return Math.max(previous, current);
  });
  return keys.filter(function (key) {
    return foo[key] == max;
  });
};

var result = findMaxProperties(bar);
$('#result').text(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

If I understand your question correctly (and if that is the case then you really need to edit it :)) then you want to look through an object and find its properties that have the highest numeric value. If that's the case, then something along those lines would do the trick.

```js
var foo = { green: 3, red: 2, blue: 1, yellow: 1, mint: 3 };

var maxValue = Number.MIN_VALUE, maxValueProperties = [];
for (var key in foo) {
  if(foo[key] == maxValue) {
    maxValueProperties.push(key);
  }
  if(foo[key] > maxValue) {
    maxValue = foo[key];
    maxValueProperties = [];
    maxValueProperties.push(key);
  }  
}

$('#result').text(maxValueProperties);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">result</div>
```